How to expose a React component from host application to a module federated child application in Micro Front End Architecture?
I was exploring the Microfront End Architecture, and I found this very useful github repo https://github.com/nebarf/module-federation-react-router-dom
My usecase is I want to expose a component from my host/shell application to my module federated child application, in this case app1. But not able to do so.
My React Component from host/shell application that I want to use in child application (app1) -
import React from 'react';

const Example = () => {
  return <div>Example</div>;
};

export default Example;

My complete webpack config for shell application -
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');

const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;
module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js', '.json'],
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'shell',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        app1: 'app1@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js',
        app2: 'app2@http://localhost:8082/remoteEntry.js',
      },
      exposes: {
        './example': './src/components/Example',
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        'react-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};


My complete webpack config for app1 application -
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');

const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;
module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8081/',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js', '.json'],
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'app1',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        exampleApp: 'shell@http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js',
      },
      exposes: {
        './App1Index': './src/bootstrap',
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        'react-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};


I am getting the following error - Cannot find module 'example/exampleApp' or its corresponding type declarations.
Where am I going wrong?
I think I am using the expose and remotes object from module federation plugin correctly only.
Can anyone help.
